# how to use gridview values to update another table in database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a `GridView` and it is bound to SQLdatasource. I edit it and the corresponding table in the database gets updated. 
Once I finish editing all the rows in the `GridView`, On a button_click I want to read each and every row in the `GridView` which has entry and use the first column **Location** in my GridView in where clause and update another different table in the database.

Kindly help. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the Column value of each row in Grid View and Update it using Update Query by creating another datasource to the corresponding SQL Table.
the following code will help you to understand better.

```
int rowscount = gv.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++)
{
           //Iterating the Grid View



        RequiredColvalue = gv.Rows[i][0].Tostring();

   //Update Statement According to your need.
}
```